# Rot18, encrypt and decrypt (python, Sublime Text)

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, character-encoding, sublimetext3

I am looking for a plugin that can encrypt/decrypt text using rot18 in Sublime Text v3.2.2.

I tried this tutorial (only rot13) but it doesn’t work for me: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-examples

I tried a lot of plugins and the only one that works fine is:
(unfortunately it is rot47)

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class Rot47Command(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        for region in self.view.sel():
            if not region.empty():
                s = self.view.substr(region)
                s = ''.join(chr(33 + ((ord(ch) + 14) % 94)) for ch in s)
                self.view.replace(edit, region, s)
```

Does anyone have any functional plugin on rot18, please?

Answer (score 2):

You can adapt your code. Here is how rot_N works:

This is the ASCII-Range up to 127:

```
a = 32  
for k in range(0,16):
    print(a+k, chr(a+k), "    ", a+16+k, chr(a+16+k), "    ", a+32+k, chr(a+32+k), "    ", 
          a+48+k, chr(a+48+k), "    ", a+64+k, chr(a+64+k), "    ", a+80+k, chr(a+80+k))

    #    32        48 0      64 @      80 P       96 `      112 p
    #    33 !      49 1      65 A      81 Q       97 a      113 q
    #    34 "      50 2      66 B      82 R       98 b      114 r
    #    35 #      51 3      67 C      83 S       99 c      115 s
    #    36 $      52 4      68 D      84 T      100 d      116 t
    #    37 %      53 5      69 E      85 U      101 e      117 u
    #    38 &      54 6      70 F      86 V      102 f      118 v
    #    39 '      55 7      71 G      87 W      103 g      119 w
    #    40 (      56 8      72 H      88 X      104 h      120 x
    #    41 )      57 9      73 I      89 Y      105 i      121 y
    #    42 *      58 :      74 J      90 Z      106 j      122 z
    #    43 +      59 ;      75 K      91 [      107 k      123 {
    #    44 ,      60 <      76 L      92 \      108 l      124 |
    #    45 -      61 =      77 M      93 ]      109 m      125 }
    #    46 .      62 >      78 N      94 ^      110 n      126 ~
    #    47 /      63 ?      79 O      95 _      111 o      127
```

ROT n means you take the `chr(ord(l)+n)`'s letter instead. You need to be carefull when wrapping around.

For calculation of rot_N the basic formular is:

```
def rot_N(n,letter):
    return chr( (ord(letter)-32+n) % (128-32) + 32)    # 128-32 = 96
```

You can test it with:

```
k="Hello Zzzzz"
print( ''.join(rot_N(18, l) for l in k))   # schould give you a tranlation
print( ''.join(rot_N(0, l) for l in k))    # should give the exact text
```

and test the inverse with:

```
k_inverse ="Zw~~!2l,,,,"
print( ''.join(rot_N(-18, l) for l in k_inverse))   # use -18 here
print( ''.join(rot_N(0, l) for l in k_inverse))
```

If you replace

> ```
> s = ''.join(chr(33 + ((ord(ch) + 14) % 94)) for ch in s)
> ```

with

```
s = ''.join(rot_N(18, ch) for ch in s))
```

you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You do not specify, but I assume you are using ROT-18 on the character set 0..9, A..Z which is 36 characters.  36/2 = 18, hence ROT-18.

ROT-13 works on the 26 alphabetic characters: 26/2 = 13.  You want to adapt that to ROT-18.

The major difference is that the alphabetic characters are continuous in the ASCII character set, and that assumption is built into the code you are copying from.  The same is true for ROT-47; the ASCII characters used are continuous.  With ROT-18, the digits 0..9 and the alphabetic characters, A..Z are not continuous in ASCII.  There is a gap between them from `:` (#58) to `@` (#64).  ASCII codes in that region are neither digits nor letters.

One solution is to set up your own array, not in the ASCII order, where the two are continuous: `[0, 1, ... 9, A, B, ... Z]`.  Write your program to work on that array.

Alternatively you can work with the ASCII codes, treating codes from #58 to #64 specially to make the shift come out right.

The first option is probably easier, and the code will be more similar to the ROT-13 example.  The main difference will be replacing the `ord()` function, which returns the ASCII code, with an equivalent function giving the position in your array.